# Instances with the same name

Tags: python, class, csv, oop

I am creating a program to manipulate my MTG card collection (Geek, I know) in which I am uploading a csv file of my collection and attempting to make an object of the individual sets with objects of the individual cards inside those sets.  All of the cards will have different attributes, as they will contain the amount of each card I own, however there are a lot of cards with the same name, but not in the same set.  I'm trying to understand what is the easiest way to perform this task and if I make an instance of a card in one set, will it be erased/overwritten if I create an instance with the same name for a different set.  Or would it just be easier (make more sense) to create and object of the sets and make a list of dictionaries for the individual cards.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv


class CardSet:
    def __init__(self, set_name):
        self.set_name = set_name

    def get_set(self):
        return self.set_name

    def add_card(card_name, card_num, amount, numb_foil, signed):
        cards = []
        card_name = Card(card_name, card_num, amount, numb_foil, signed)
        cards.append(card_name)
        return cards


class Card:
    def __init__(self, card_name, card_num, amount, numb_foil, signed):
        self.card_name = card_name
        self.card_num = card_num
        self.amount = amount
        self.numb_foil = numb_foil
        self.signed = signed


def csv_reader():
    # upload csv file
    cards = csv.reader(open('Collection.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf8'))
    list_sets = []  # keeps a tally of set names, as to not duplicate set objects
    list_obj_sets = []  # list of set objects to search through

    # Make a list of individual sets in collection, then make an instance of that card set
    # row[2] = Card Name, row[4] = card number, row[0] = amount owned, row[6] = foil owned, row[7] = signed
    for row in cards:
        # if set object does not exist, create object and add card to set
        if row[3] not in list_sets:  # row[3] contains set name
            list_sets.append(row[3])
            row[3] = CardSet(row[3])  # create set object
            list_obj_sets.append(row[3])
            row[3].add_card(row[2], row[4], row[0], row[6], row[7])  # create card object
        else:
            # if set object exists, add card to set
            for sets in list_obj_sets:  # find set object
                if sets.set_name == row[3]:
                    sets.add_card(row[2], row[4], row[0], row[6], row[7])  # create card object


csv_reader()
```

Thanks for the help.
-pyRN

Comment: I suggest you to finish your program (if it's not too much work) and post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) because there are multiple issues with your code. If you do this, make sure that program gives correct output, include some data from `Collection.csv` and ask questions about things that you are not sure about.

Comment: I am attempting to finish this program.  Unfortunately I feel as though I am taking one step forward, two steps back.  I will do as you recommend and post to CodeReview once I have it working to an extent.   I am just curious as to the areas you say have multiple issues (I'm trying to learn and correct mistakes).  Thanks.

Comment: The most important thing is that you don't need to use classes here. The rule of thumb is that if you have a class with 2 methods, one of which is `__init__`, then [it shouldn't be a class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). You can say that your `CardSet` has 3 methods, but `add_card` is a static method which does only appending to a list, if you take constructing `Card`s out of it.

Comment: I don't know how are you going to use cards and sets of cards in the future, so I can't tell you definitely what type of data you should use. Maybe `list`, maybe `dict`, maybe [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Comment: Great video you sent me, very informative.  Although in my head I believe that I can make more methods for the classes that could be used, I'm thinking now that dictionaries will probably be the way to go.  Thanks for your help.